# Python Twisted - Windows 7 Command Line

Tags: python, twisted, punjab

I'm trying to install the PunJab (https://github.com/twonds/punjab) in Windows 7

I install the python. 2.7.5, Twisted 13.1.0, Zope Interface 4.0.5.

I set the `C:\Python27`\ And `C:\Python27\Scripts\` to ambient variables.

I try to run: `twistd -y punjab.tac` in command line but it's don't recognize.

I'm new in python. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not that good with `git`, but you can just download and install it.. why not?

Comment: I just downloaded the files from github

Answer (score 0):

Run this

In terminal go to the folder contaiing punjab
like

```
 cd punjab
```

Run this

```
python setup.py
```

then it will install that module